# How to retrieve API Usage report for LinkedIn application so throttle limit is not reached?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there an API call to retrieve API usage report for my LinkedIn application? 
I know that at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer I can login and observe the API usage for my application. However, I would like to automate this process (inside a server written in Python) so that I can know if I am getting close to the throttle limits, without having a counter inside the server, as I am trying to keep it as stateless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I see on [LinkedIn developer forum](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-retrieve-api-usage-report-linkedin-application-so-throttle-limit-not-reached), there is no API for this purpose:

> We do not have an API that gives you the usage report. Best way right
>   now is to see the current usage on your application details page or
>   maintaing a counter on your server as you mentioned.